# Julia, what's `obtainer::Function = identity`?

Tags: julia

I'm diving into the docs of Agents.jl and I found the following function definition:

```
get_data(a, s::Symbol, obtainer::Function = identity) = obtainer(getproperty(a, s))
```

but I'm not able to get documentation on what `obtainer()` does, I only get the following message when hovering over `obtainer()`:
`obtainer::Function = identity`

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 3):

`obtainer` can be any function taking one positional argument. The argument passed to it will be property `s` of `a`. By default this function is `identity`, in which case you just get this property returned by `get_data` without any transformation.

Comment: Not any function (= "thing with methods"), only any `Function`... cf. `get_data((;a = 'a'), :a, Int)`.

Comment: and why would you use an `obtainer` if it returns (kinda) the same thing?

Comment: @phipsgabler - a function is required; but not any callable is accepted. In particular constructors and functors are not allowed.

Comment: @arnle - if you do not see a need for this then probably you can ignore this argument. In general it can be useful if you are not interested in the argument istelf but in its transformation (e.g. absolute value or log).